# Hierarchy of users

Tags: 7

I want to do like that one user should have multiple child users, for example team lead user and team members with proper permissions. Can i do this thing in drupal 7.26?

Comment: you can take a look on https://www.drupal.org/project/subuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using the [User Relationships](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_relationships) module

> Administrators are able create relationship types (friend, coworker, etc). Relationship types can be setup to be one-way or mutual. If a relationship type is one-way (subscriber) only the requester is shown as relating to the requestee. Relationship types can also be set as needing or not needing approval.
>
> Administrators can give users the option to auto approve relationships on a per-relationship type basis.

If you want to assign a user under another user you can use [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references)  module

you can use This project provides D7 versions of the 'node_reference' and 'user_reference' field types, that were part of the CCK package in D6, at functional parity with the D6 counterparts. See http://drupal.org/node/533222 for details.

Comment: Thanks Krishna, i have installed this module but we can't assign user to another user using this module, and if is it possible then can you please send me example or best tutorial for it? and also this module is not workingwith 7.26

Comment: @virangjethava you can use 'user reference' from that module (after installation)

Answer (score 0):

[Subuser](https://www.drupal.org/project/subuser) module seems work for you.

> This module allows users to be given the permission to create subusers. The subusers may 
>       then be automatically assigned a role or roles. The parent of the subusers then has the 
>       ability to manager the users they have created.

Customize settings links
please visit `admin/settings/subuser`